# How to add a single Key value to existing Java 8 stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

Here is what I do to populate my static map

```
public static final Map<String, FooBar> mapEnum = 

Arrays.stream(FooBarEnum.values())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(e-> StringUtils.upperCase(e.name), e -> e));
```

I want to add another single key-value to this map.

```
mapEnum.put("xx", FooBar.A);
```

Here is the enum

```
public enum FooBar {
   A("a"), B("b"), C("c");
}
```

My static map will look like this after map is constructed

```
{"a":FooBar.A, "b": FooBar.B, "c": FooBar.C, "xx": Foobar.A}
```

Is it possible to include the explicit put call into `Collectors.toMap()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually don't see the need to use Java Streams for that. You simply can use the `static` block to initialize `mapEnum` and `put` additional values in it:

```
public static final Map<String, FooBar> mapEnum;

static {
    mapEnum = Arrays.stream(FooBar.values())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(FooBar::getName, Function.identity()));
    mapEnum.put("xx", FooBar.A);
    // ...
}
```

> **`Collectors.toMap()`**: There are no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the {@code Map} returned.

To ensure the mutability of the `Map` returned by `Collectors.toMap()`, so you can use `Map.put()` afterwards better use this:

```
Arrays.stream(FooBar.values())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), Function.identity(), (a, b) -> a, HashMap::new));
```

If you really want to use java streams you can use this:

```
public static final Map<String, FooBar> mapEnum = Stream.concat(
        Stream.of(FooBar.values()).map(e -> Map.entry(e.getName(), e)),
        Stream.of(Map.entry("xx", FooBar.A))
).collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Or if you also want to add all names to the enum value itself you can change your class like this:

```
public static enum FooBar {
    A("a", "xx"), B("b"), C("c");

    private String[] names;

    FooBar(String... names) {
        this.names = names;
    }

    public String[] getNames() {
        return names;
    }
}
```

And use this to create the map:

```
public static final Map<String, FooBar> mapEnum = Stream.of(FooBar.values())
        .flatMap(e -> Arrays.stream(e.getNames()).map(n -> Map.entry(n, e)))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Prior to Java 9 use `new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>()` instead of `Map.entry()`. If you need the map to be sorted use `LinkedHashMap::new` with `Collectors.toMap()`.

Comment: what do you mean "to ensure mutabality of put"

Comment: so if you dont explicitly do HashMap::new, what do we get? immutable map?

Comment: @brainstorm Looking at the source code it is a `HashMap`, but as it says in the docs I shared it is not guaranteed to be a `HashMap` in feature releases. I just wanted to mention that. Personally I would just stick with the default `toMap()` in most cases.

Comment: one other question is FooBar::getName? how do I get capitalizedVersion on it? i.e something like this "FooBar::StringUtils.upperCase(getName)"

Comment: @brainstorm That's just a short version of `o -> o.getName()`. You can use `o -> StringUtils.upperCase(o.get name()); like you have in your question.

Answer (score 3):

If you're open to using a third party library you can create a static `ImmutableMap` inline with a `Stream` using [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections).

```
public static final ImmutableMap<String, FooBar> MAP_ENUM =
        Arrays.stream(FooBar.values())
                .collect(Collectors2.toMap(FooBar::getName, fooBar -> fooBar))
                .withKeyValue("xx", FooBar.A)
                .toImmutable();

public enum FooBar {
    A("a"), B("b"), C("c");

    private String name;

    FooBar(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

You can also simplify the code slightly by using native Eclipse Collections APIs.

```
public static final ImmutableMap<String, FooBar> MAP_ENUM =
        ArrayAdapter.adapt(FooBar.values())
                .groupByUniqueKey(FooBar::getName)
                .withKeyValue("xx", FooBar.A)
                .toImmutable();
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections

Comment: Very nice solution. Did not know Eclipse Collections before.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `Collectors::collectAndThen` to modify the resulted map

```
Arrays.stream(FooBarEnum.values())
        .collect(Collectors.collectAndThen(
                    Collectors.toMap(e-> StringUtils.upperCase(e.name), 
                        Function.identity()), FooBarEnum::addCustom));
```

the following method is in enum

```
static Map<String, FooBar> addCustom(Map<String, FooBarEnum> map) {
    map.put("xx", FooBar.A);
    return map;
}
```

Comment: `Collectors.toMap` does not say that the resulting `Map` is mutable though... but also this looks like way too much for a single `map.put(...)` afterwards

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly pass it to Collectors.toMap(). You can see all the overrides available in the javadocs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function- .

However, you can make sure your stream has all the pairs needed to construct the map, before you call toMap by using Stream.concat. You concat the pairs from the enum, and the manual pairs you want to add.

My standalone code has to define the Pair class, but since you used StringUtils, I imagine you have a library that already includes Pair so you don't need to define it.

Code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class Main {

    private static enum  FooBar {
        A("a"), B("b"), C("c");
        private String name;
        FooBar(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    public static class Pair {
        String a;
        FooBar b;
        Pair(String a, FooBar b) {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        System.out.println(
            Stream.concat( 
                Arrays.stream(FooBar.values()).map(e -> new Pair(e.name.toUpperCase(), e)),
                Stream.of(new Pair("xx", FooBar.A))
            )
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(pair -> pair.a, pair -> pair.b))
        );
    }

}
```

Output:

```
{xx=A, A=A, B=B, C=C}
```